# I have many problems in magento 2.3.2 version

Tags: magento2.3, backend

before I have configured the version 2.3.1 and I upgrade it to 2.3.2 version, but now have this problem, when I click the option view in orders, in the developer mode, it throws me attached message.
[image]

When I change to production mode, it ignores the Exception but the information in order doesn't appear correctly.
[image]

Comment: Is there any error in console or in logs file. ?

Comment: negative, just only the message what you see in the first photo.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Magento 2.3.2 quite a while now and never occurred something like this. Had an issue with the order and I fixed it with https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22743

If this is still occurring, if you could give me the test server access.

Comment: i fixed that problem, so one extension had what affect product grid when i uninstall the grid back to the normal position.